# From where and how to download talend mdm Sourcecode ?

Tags: talend

I want to download  talendmdm source code.Where this can be  downloaded From ? Kindly provide the inputs so that i can download the source code.Kindly provide the inputs .

Answer (score 2):

As easy as going svn on talendforge :)

http://www.talendforge.org/trac/tom/